# Unable to connect to PHP Websocket Server

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am trying to set up a PHP websocket server using [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/).  Everything I have done is exactly per the phpwebsocket files (with the exception of changing the server to localhost and adjusting ports).  I am trying to do this on Windows 7 with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.17.  I have also tried several other examples that I have found on the web.

With all of the different set ups I have tried, I have not been able to get Firefox to connect to the socket.  I have also tried using Telnet to connect but have not had any luck there.  I feel like there must a step that I am missing because I get the same result with everything I try.  I have also disabled Windows Firewall which did not change the result.

Any thoughts on what might be keeping this setup from being able to get a connection?

Comment: is someone "listening" on the other side? did you check that port's status with "netstat" command line utility?

Comment: Well I am trying to connect to myself so I'm not sure if that is creating a conflict with the same computer talking/listening.  I did check netstat/resource monitor and confirmed that the port is open and "listening".  I'm not sure how relevant it is but I should probably note that I am also connected to a wireless router.

Comment: phpwebsocket doesn't appear to be maintained and only supports the older variant of the websocket protocol.  See a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845502/web-socket-not-working-in-firefox-12/10850392#10850392) for a similar discussion