# Web socket not working in Firefox 12

Tags: php, websocket, php-socket

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://192.168.0.155:5555/socket/server3.php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!("WebSocket" in window)){
alert('not available');
}else{
_init(); 
}
});
function _init(){
     var websocket;
     var host = 'ws://192.168.0.155:5555/socket/server3.php';
     try{
     websocket = new WebSocket(host);
     websocket.onopen = function(evt){ onOpen(evt); };
     websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt); };
     websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt); };
     }catch(exception){
     alert(exception);
     }
     }

  function onOpen(evt){
    $('.logger_screen').append('Connected');
      }

  function onClose(evt){
      $('.logger_screen').append('Disconnected');
       }

  function onMessage(evt){
    $('.logger_screen').append(evt.data);
   }
```

wts wrong with my code ??

Comment: I'm no expert on the matter but I've seen it used with `http://` instead of `ws://` before. Did you give that a try?

Comment: socket is not for http requests.socket are mainly used for tcp, udp, ssl etc. but not for http. websocket use ws protocol for socket connection and in this case it is ws....

Comment: Firefox 12 works fine with my simple websocket server.  What server are you trying to connect to?  Also, what happens when you try to connect (is an exception thrown for instance)?  It might be worth adding an onerror function and logging calls to it too.

Comment: i am using simple socket server in php. I also used other scripts too but when i try to run the client then gives error. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/
open this url, i have tried this example too, but giving same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of your comments, I think you're using [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) on the server.  This project doesn't seem to be maintained and hasn't stayed up to date with changes in the websocket protocol spec.

There are two incompatible versions of the websocket protocol in use.  Safari still uses the original (now deprecated) [Hixie](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) variant which phpwebsocket implements; Firefox, IE10 and Chrome use the newer [Hybi](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) variant.

To test this out, you could try using Safari to to execute your javascript.

I'm not sure what options you have if you want to use PHP on the server and need to support more than Safari.  I can see one [open source server](https://github.com/GulDmitry/php-websocket-server) which should support all the browsers listed above.  Alternatively, if you want to try writing your own server, there are quite a few questions posted here, under the websocket tag, that you could take inspiration from.