# Site loading on chrome and opera but partially loading on firefox and safari

Tags: php, css, html, firefox

I am facing this strange issue with one of my site

Please try opening the below link in firefox and chrome

http://www.substationdesign.com.au/substation-design

This is working all ok on chrome but not rendering properly on firefox. Earlier it was working all ok in firefox as well.

Please find the screenshots below for both the browsers
[image]
[image]

Refer : http://web.archive.org/web/20140510214349/http://www.substationdesign.com.au/

Things I have tried

- Tested with older version of firefox not working
- Tested with W3C validator online. Is giving the similar issue as it is not able to render the page properly. Where as the same site is validated in desktop application
- Tried removing all the js still getting the similar issue. Not able to render the HTML
- Link Working all ok on Chrome and Opera but not on Firefox and Safari

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, please post the relevant code (not more) inside this question. Posting links to arbitrary sites is _not_ a replacement for that. In addition try to be more specific what it is that is not working as expected. "not loading properly" can mean many different things. There is no sense in us _guessing_ what you might refer to. PLease also make sure that you check if there are any error messages in 1. the http servers log file and 2. the browsers javascript console. If so, post them here inside the question as well.

Comment: @arkascha please try opening the link on chrome and firefox then you might able to understand my point.

Comment: Sorry no, I certainly will _not_ click on some link where I have no idea what to expect.

Comment: Then could you please help me in framing the question coz this is some very wierd issue I am facing

Comment: Start by doing a screen shot for example and add it inside the question. Explain what the issue is.

Comment: @arkascha screenshots added

Comment: it's working on firefox for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of one my friend got this fixed.
The issue is kind of wierd, when I remove the code for Gzip it working fine. I guess this is the issue with encoding. Google supports it but Firefox and safari don't.

I Comapared my code with my previous backup and checked what is wrong. Below is my code difference.

https://www.diffchecker.com/xbr6lyvr

Comment: Post the code here, the link might get obsolete at some point of time.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox's console says

> The connection to ws://ins15.hotjar.com/api/v1/client/userdata was interrupted while the page was loading.

It may be a compatibility issue between phpwebsocket and different versions of FF.

This has been partially addressed before.

[Web socket not working in Firefox 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845502/web-socket-not-working-in-firefox-12)

EDIT:

I used http://www.websocket.org/echo.html to test this out on Firefox after manually enabling WebSockets. Your site "works" but still won't load for me.

Comment: Several plugins can disable WebSockets in Firefox... Have you checked your site across different versions of Firefox, or on different computers? You could enter About:Config to navigate to Firefox's settings and manually enable WS.

Comment: Yes have tested across multiple systems and multiple operating systems too. Also tested on various versions of firefox too on browserstack still not luck